# Reload a model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What's the best way to refresh a given model attribute?

I.e., functionally, I want this:

```
post.body = Post.find(post.id).body
```

with a nicer syntax. Maybe

```
post.reload_body!
```

**Edit:** I only want to reload a *single* attribute (not all attributes at once)

Comment: What do you mean be refreshing a model attribute? What is the context?

Comment: Question title and content are conflicting. Do you want to refresh only the specified attribute or is it ok to refresh them all?

Comment: @Heikki: the specified attribute (I updated the question to make this clearer)

Comment: Could you elaborate why do you need to reload only one attribute? Better chance to figure out nice syntax if we understand the whole setup.

Comment: Here's one use case: I have a form that masks an SSN like "*****1234". If I detect that the SSN coming in is just the masked version of the current SSN, I want to bypass validations on that field and leave it alone. If the SSN coming in from the form is anything else, I want to validate and attempt to save the new SSN. In order to know the difference I need the SSN from the database (which I've encrypted of course).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Beats me why you'd want to do such a thing, but:

```
def reload_attribute(attr)
  value = self.class.where(:id=>id).select(attr).first[attr]
  self[attr] = value
end
```

This issues a `SELECT` that retrieves just the one column and assigns its value to the attribute in the current model instance. Call with (eg):

```
post = Post.find(1)
post.reload_attribute(:body)
```

Really though, you should just go with `post.reload` ([doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/reload)). Unless you have hugely wide columns that impose some performance cost on doing `SELECT *`

Comment: this will also be a problem if you have (say) custom accessors etc.

Comment: The use case I see is to avoid clearing the relations cache as well. If I refresh only one attribute of the object, the already loaded relations won't trigger a new SQL call afterwards.

Comment: Alternatively `self[attr] = self.class.select(attr).find_by(id: id)[attr]`